# problems with http file upload to wcf-rest service

Tags: wcf, file, rest, file-upload

I would like to upload a file using a form like this:

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8090/MyService/" 
      method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>Select File<br>
     <input name="Datei" type="file" size="50">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </p>
</form>
```

And have a wcf service like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDocumentConverter
{
    [OperationContract, WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/", Method = "POST")]
    void UploadFile(Stream fileContents);         
}
```

I have two problems with this. When I write the stream back into a file it does not only contain the file data but also some http stuff. This seems odd. Is there nice way to get the raw file data?:

```
-----------------------------67832811011758
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Datei"; filename="haha.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

ÿØÿà...
```

The original file looks like this:

```
ÿØÿà...
```

Secondly I would like to have the filename in wcf. Ideally like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDocumentConverter
{
    [OperationContract, WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/{filename}", Method = "POST")]
    void UploadFile(string filename, Stream fileContents);         
}
```

But this is not working, because I don't know how to integrate the filename into the url using the form/input stuff.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".